# How to use telescoping series to find: $\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{r+2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, telescopic-series

I am a bit confused in this one, how do i do the required modification in this case?

Comment: This series does not telescope.  This is just the harmonic series but offset.  Letting $H_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$, the $n$'th [Harmonic Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), this is $H_{n+2} - 1.5$.  It does not simplify further.

Comment: ohk, thanks i understood, can you please tell me in what cases we can/should use telescoping series?

Comment: Telescoping series are when you can rewrite some sum $\sum(a_k)$ as $\sum(b_k-b_{k+1})$ or similar, possibly involving more terms at a time, allowing the majority of the terms in the middle to cancel, leaving just the one or a few terms at the beginning and just the one or a few terms at the end after all of the cancellation has happened.  Commonly disguised telescoping sums can be seen as a result of partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: alright i got it!

Comment: @Vega It's possible that this question could be a typo when you received it, and was meant to be $\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{r(r + 2)}$? That series would telescope.

Comment: @ Theo Bendit no the question is not that, in fact, i made this myself, thinking if i could use telescoping in this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, $\sum_{r = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{r + 2}$ does not telescope. As for an example of a sum that does telescope, consider $\sum_{r = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{r(r + 1)}$. We can rewrite this summation as

$$\sum_{r = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{r(r + 1)} = \sum_{r = 1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{r + 1}\right) = \left(\frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{2}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3}\right) + \cdots + \left(\frac{1}{n} -  \frac{1}{n + 1}\right),$$

and we can pair off terms to see that the entire sum ends up being $1 - \frac{1}{n + 1} = \frac{n}{n + 1}$.

Answer (score 0):

As many people have mentioned, this sum does not telescope. A summation series telescopes only if there is addition and subtraction involved. The addition and subtraction causes terms to cancel out. For example, the summation series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1n - \frac1{n+1}$ telescopes because the subtraction allows parts of the series to cancel with parts of the series that come after. For a product series, it should have multiplication and division so that the operations cancel each other out. For example, the product $\prod_{n=0}^\infty \frac1n*({n+1})$ uses multiplication in the previous term to cancel out with division in the current term.